# Is there a way to see if process listening on TCP port receives a message?

Tags: process, tcp, debugging, netfilter

According to `tcpdump`, my server receives the following TCP packet:

```
12:52:29.603233 00:19:e2:9e:df:f0 
00:16:3e:6a:25:3f, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.10.10.65.38869 
192.168.215.82.22: Flags [S], seq 567054335, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2096335479 ecr 0,nop,wscale 0], length 0
```

As seen above, it's a TCP SYN packet to TCP port 22, where in my case listens a `sshd`. I would like to see, if this TCP packet reaches the `sshd` process. I guess one option would be to restart the `sshd` in debug mode. However, are there any other clever tools/methods to see if process listening on TCP port receives a message? In case of TCP SYN packet, I guess it's the kernel TCP/IP stack which will send the TCP SYN+ACK and not the `sshd`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> However, are there any other clever tools/methods to see if process listening on TCP port receives a message?

You can use `strace` with `-e trace=network`. This is what it prints on accepting a TCP connection, receiving an HTTP request, sending an HTTP response and closing the connection:

```
$ strace -v -f -e trace=network -p `cat logs/my_server.pid`
Process 2361 attached with 44 threads - interrupt to quit
[pid  2422] accept(11, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(56289), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.30.1.60")}, [16]) = 14
[pid  2422] getsockname(14, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(7754), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.30.1.60")}, [16]) = 0
[pid  2422] setsockopt(14, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
[pid  2422] setsockopt(14, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0
[pid  2422] getsockopt(14, SOL_SOCKET, SO_OOBINLINE, [515004615020773376], [4]) = 0
[pid  2388] recvfrom(14, "GET /OPEN_", 10, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = 10
[pid  2388] recvfrom(14, "GET /OPEN_SESSION?LOGIN=HAS_ADMI"..., 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 246
[pid  2388] sendto(14, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: MY_SER"..., 192, 0, NULL, 0) = 192
[pid  2388] sendto(14, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding = '"..., 680, 0, NULL, 0) = 680
[pid  2361] --- SIGIO (I/O possible) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid  2388] recvfrom(14, "", 4096, 0, NULL, NULL) = 0
[pid  2388] shutdown(14, 2 /* send and receive */) = 0
```

Comment: And with colors: `strace $CMD 2>&1 > /dev/null | vim -c ':set syntax=strace' -`.